# How to troubleshoot/bug report a problem that only appears right after startup?

Tags: troubleshooting, session

Recently the network manager applet has been crashing immediately after startup and only at startup. It remains stable throughout the rest of the day.  How would I begin to discover what the issue is?  There must be a general method of attack on a problem like this.  Normally I would try running the program from the terminal to see if any error messages are printed but nm-applet does not seem to crash once I restart it.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into `~/.xsession-errors` for relevant error messages.

Answer (score 1):

dmesg.  I'd also collect the chipset and driver versions of all your network devices and confirm there are no open bugs in Launchpad for network manager.

Comment: I know that you can view dmesg using System>Administration>Log File Viewer but what would be the best way to find the chipset and driver versions?  I have found a bug on launchpad that might be related but of course nm-applet seems to be cooperating for now, so I will wait and see  what happens.  With yours and Jan's response I will wait for the next time and hopefully be prepared to make a useful bug report.